# sam local start-api Unable to resolve property

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I have next command: `sam local start-api -t some.yaml -d 9229 --env-vars some.json`
in some yaml file I have env variables and in some.json these var's are configured.
But when I am running this command with --debug parameter, it shows me next output:

```
local start-api command is called
No Parameters detected in the template
Unable to resolve property SOME_VAR: None. Leaving as is.
```